# Using SDF instead of URDF with ROS Robot State Publisher

Tags: ros, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

With **URDF** models, you can use `robot_state_publisher` to have the joints published in `tf`. Since this needs the `<robot>` tag, it does not work with **SDF** models. If you try to `roslaunch` for a SDF it would say

```
Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
```

Everything else works fine in gazebo but the state publisher dies

Is there any way I can use **robot state publisher** with SDF? Maybe include URDF into the SDF? Or specify the `<robot>` tag in it somehow?

---

**TL;DR:**

I have found many other questions related to this question but none had a positive answer and most of them are more than 5 years old. However,

- [This answer](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/62/sdf-vs-urdf-what-should-one-use/) suggests that you can do anything with SDF that is possible in URDF.
- [This question](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/4192/problem-with-sdf-files-or-robot_description-parameter/) has an answer suggesting an alternative by having both URDF and SDF but it's an ugly solution
- There's this [old unanswered question](https://answers.ros.org/question/204803/robot_state_publisher-with-sdf-files/) as well

I want to create a 6 wheeled robot model with two wheels having **shock absorbers** (prismatic joints with damping and spring actions). To my understanding, [this cannot be done using URDF](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint#line-67)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25511/using-sdf-instead-of-urdf-with-ros-robot-state-publisher/) by [teshansj](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28014/teshansj/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My problem was URDF not being able to do some stuff SDF can. But I wasn't aware of the `<gazebo>` tags at the time. Using them, I was able to do what I wanted and no need of SDF has come up after that.

I got an answer in [answers.gazebo](https://answers.ros.org/question/357026/using-sdf-instead-of-urdf-with-robot-state-publisher/). Linked for future reference for anyone in need

---

Originally posted by [teshansj](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28014/teshansj/) with karma: 5 on 2020-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0